# Get models list in CakePHP 2

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

I'm trying to get a complete list of all models under `app/Model`.

Already tried `App::objects('Model')` but it only retrieves loaded models.

Is this possible in CakePHP 2?

Comment: using cake 2.8 it gives all the models, not just the loaded ones

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research I found that `App::objects('Model')` returns all models under `app/Models` but it doesn't include Plugin models.

To include all models (app models and plugin models) I created the next function:

```
/**
 * Get models list
 *
 * @return array
 */
public static function getModels()
{
    // Get app models
    $models = App::objects('Model');

    $models = array_combine($models, $models);

    // Get plugins models
    $pluginsFolder = new Folder(APP . 'Plugin');

    $plugins = $pluginsFolder->read();

    foreach ( $plugins[0] as $plugin ) {

        $pluginModels = App::objects($plugin . '.Model');

        foreach ($pluginModels as $pluginModel) {

            $models[$plugin . '.' . $pluginModel] = $plugin . '.' . $pluginModel;

        }

    }

    // Exclude tableless and application models
    $dataSource = ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default');

    $sources = $dataSource->listSources();

    foreach($models as $key => $model) {

        $table = Inflector::tableize(self::modelName($key));

        if (stripos($model, 'AppModel') > -1 || !in_array($table, $sources)) {

            unset($models[$key]);

        }

    }

    return $models;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe late but here is my version:
(loops through plugin models, and retrieves the table associated by opening the file, and searching for the variable **$useTable**)

```
/**
 * Get models list.
 * Retrieved from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38622473/get-models-list-in-cakephp-2
 * @return array
*/
public static function getModels() {

    // Get app models
    $models = App::objects('Model');
    $models = array_combine($models, $models);

    // Get plugins models
    $pluginsFolder = new Folder(APP . 'Plugin');
    $plugins = $pluginsFolder->read();

    foreach ( $plugins[0] as $plugin ) {
        $pluginModels = App::objects($plugin . '.Model');
        foreach ($pluginModels as $pluginModel) {
            $fullPath = APP.'Plugin'.DS.$plugin.DS."Model".DS.$pluginModel.".php";
            $models[$plugin . '.' . $pluginModel] = $fullPath;
        }
    }

    foreach($models as $model => $modelPath) {
        if(file_exists($modelPath)) {
            $data = file_get_contents($modelPath);

            $find = array();
            $find[] = "useTable = '";
            $find[] = "useTable='";
            $find[] = "useTable= '";
            $find[] = "useTable ='";

            foreach($find as $condition) {
                $pos = strrpos($data, $condition);
                if($pos !== false ) {
                    $pos+=(strlen($condition));

                    $tableName = substr($data, $pos, (strpos($data, "';", $pos)-$pos));
                    debug($tableName);
                }    
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CakePHP v2

In AppController

```
if (in_array('YOUR_MODEL', $this->uses)) {
    //found
}
```

Comment: How does this returns a list of used models?

Comment: $this->uses holds an array of models used in your controller.  Obviously does not account for models used in plugins.  Simple hack if working with a small project.